# IIS 10 Rewrite To Acknowledgement Page Fails on Initial Request

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am new to the rewrite module and I'm very confused. I'm trying to use a rewrite rule to make all requests not originating from the local URL to be forced to a policy acknowledgement page. Once on the page, they can click a button and be sent to their original URL. I'm trying to capture the original URL and add it to the redirect URL query and then use that original URL in the "Accept" button click event to set the "location.href" to the original URL. Rule is below. Since the initial request from a user does not have the HOST request header yet, the rule seems to ignore it and doesn't match the condition, allowing the request to pass through. I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance. Maybe I'm using the wrong approach. This all to comply with the DoD requirement to show the banner on entry to the site.

```
<rule name="Show Banner" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="test.domain.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="banner/banner-Popup.htm?u=https://test.domain.com{URL}"
    logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Did you use a tool like Wireshark to confirm that "the initial request from a user does not have the HOST request header yet"? Host header is too important to miss in modern days, so make sure you don't make wrong assumptions.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view the detailed request process, or you can give an example to explain your requirements, I will make demo for you.

Comment: @Lex Li  
I did not use a port monitor, but I did use browser developer tools to verify the host header is not present on the initial request.

Comment: @samwu  I'm not sure what you are asking for as an example. I included the rule that I have created, but doesn't work. As I said in my original post, the initial request doesn't have a Host request header, so it passes through to the requested page. Therefore, there is no failed request log entry.

Comment: What I mean is to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.